# How to use a value of one variable from one function into another function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.4

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from selenium import webdriver

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        menu1=QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        for c in [" ","snak","python"]:
            menu1.addItem(c)

        menu1.activated[str].connect(self.b)
    def b(self,a):
        print (a) #it gives me the value selected in the menu option but the problem is i want to use the same value of "a" in another function

    def handleButton(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get('http://google.com')
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("a") # value of a should be same as value printed in function b

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you expect your code to do? Where is the problem? What have you tried so far, and how did it not meet your needs? Please [edit] your question with some more explanation.

Comment: What variable are you trying to share?